# How can I assign a property to a collection based on the route to be used in the view?

Tags: laravel-5

What I am trying to accomplish is a full index of surveys to be converted to JSON for use with javascript (vue). When the user is on a route with a survey id defined (ie: /survey/1) that instance in the collection would get active = true.

Right now my solution is to use a view composer to loop through each survey and compare it to the current route parameters.

```
class AppComposer
{

    /**
     * @param Survey $surveys
     */
    public function __construct(Survey $surveys)
    {
        $allSurveys = $surveys->all()->toArray();
        if (!empty($surveyId = Route::current()->parameters()['survey'])){
            foreach ($allSurveys as $index => $survey){
                $allSurveys[$index]['active']=false;
                if ($survey['id'] == $surveyId){
                    $allSurveys[$index]['active']=true;
                }
            }

        }
        $this->allSurveys=$allSurveys;

    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('appData', $this->allSurveys);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Laravel, but I know there has to be a simpler way to to this.

I would prefer not to make a separate http request using vue-resource.

So, is there a better way to add this logic to the collection without having to run through a view composer, loop through each survey and compare it with the route parameters to add an active flag on the current one?

Answer (score 0):

Simplified using Laravel.

```
public function __construct(Survey $surveys)
{
    $this->allSurveys = $surveys->all()->sortBy('status')->each(function ($item, $key) {
        $item->active = ($item->id == Route::current()->getParameter('survey'));
    });
}
```